# Laravel Yajra Datatable Duplicating Data When page number change

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, datatable, yajra-datatable

Laravel Yajra DataTable Duplicating Data when changing the page number.

[page 01 data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja4bQ.png)

[page 02 data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsNdJ.png)

Some data will appear on all pages (duplicate) ..for example, id 513.

```html
if ($request->ajax()) {


            $data = Lead::with('getSource', 'getPreferredProject', 'tasks')
                            ->where('is_verified', 1)
                            ->whereNull('attended_by')
                            ->whereNull('leads_maker_status')
                            ->where(function ($q) {
                                $q->where('lead_stage_id','!=',6)->orWhereNull('lead_stage_id'); 
                            })                   
            ->orderBy('verified_at', 'DESC');

            return DataTables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()

            ->editColumn('lead_date', function ($data) {
                return $data->lead_date != '0000-00-00' ?date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->lead_date)) : '';
            })
            ->editColumn('verified_at', function ($data) {
                return $data->verified_at != '0000-00-00' ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->verified_at)) : '';
            })
          
               ->rawColumns(['lead_date','verified_at'])
                
                 ->make(true);
        }
```

**Request Function**

```html
 function getLeadsMakerData() {
            $('#leadsMakerTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                paging: true,
                responsive: true,
                scrollX: false,

                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('leads-maker.index') }}",
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                        name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'enquirer_name',
                        name: 'enquirer_name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'lead_date',
                        name: 'lead_date'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'verified_at',
                        name: 'verified_at'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mobile',
                        name: 'mobile'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'email',
                        name: 'email'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'source',
                        name: 'source'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'preferred_project',
                        name: 'preferred_project'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'action',
                        name: 'action',
                        searchable: false,
                        orderable: false,
                    },
                ],
                "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                    $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
                },
                lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100]
            });
        }
```

this is the source code I am using to send the request

and I am calling this method inside $( document ).ready().

Comment: Could you please share the initialization code?

Comment: Sure..i will add with my question,please check

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with the function It's perfect! Could you please share the JS code?

Comment: Added ,Please Check